# Reading č, ć and đ from MySQL using .NET Core service

Tags: mysql, .net-core

I tried number of options for reading ć, ć and đ signs from MySQL database but with  no success.
Instead of: šuma, žeton, čevepčići, šuma, đak, džon

I am getting: šuma, žeton, ?evep?i?i, šuma, ?ak, džon.

The collation of MySQl table is utfmb4- default collation. The very same .NET Core service having trouble reading mentioned signs from database can do insert operation perfectly. So just a read is a problem.

Some members here on SO advised that  executing following "SET character" commands after opening connection to database should help, but this was not true for me.

```
 string commColl = "SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4'; set character_set_results = 'utf8mb4'; SET collation_connection = 'utf8mb4_general_ci'; SET NAMES UTF8;";

            MySqlCommand commCollation = new MySqlCommand(commColl, conn);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                commCollation.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, I tried with setting to 'utf8' also without success.
Besides, I have also put the CharSet part into connection string:

```
 private readonly string connString = "host=aurora-host.wert.net;user=asop;password=ooppoo;database=test;Connect Timeout=10;CharSet=utf8;";
```

Show CREATE TABLE:

> CREATE TABLE `FEEDBACK` (
>     `EntryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `AccessCode` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>     `DocumentPath` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>     `FreeText` varchar(4000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>     `DateInsert` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
>     `SurveyID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     `Document` blob,
>     `DocumentExtension` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>     `CompanyID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (`EntryID`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=98 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: .NET Strings are UTF16. The very page you posted proves there's no issue in .NET's side - SO is an ASP.NET site. `can do insert operation perfectly` are you sure?  `?` is the replacement character used when converting **non Unicode** text using the wrong codepage. When reading *to* Unicode with the wrong page the Unicode Replacement character is used  �

Comment: What is the *column's* collation? UTF8 on the column and `Charset=UTF8` should be enough. Anything else will only cause trouble

Comment: the text is inserted into mySQL through web page which uses the mentioned service, In the MySQLWorkBench I can read the text as it was entered 1/1

Comment: Many people pointed out that UTF8 is not enough for MySQL but it should be utf8mb4 collation, which is the colaltion for my table. The datatype of column is VarChar

Comment: many people pointed out something that isn't enough after all. The choice of replacement character means the problem occured *before* the text's conversion to Unicode. You haven't posted the table creation schema anyway so it's not possible to replicate the problem and try to see what's wrong

Comment: It could easily be that the data is stored as ISO-8859-1, which works just fine when you try to read the data with a client that uses this codepage too. When you try to convert that to Unicode, you'd get the error characters. I'd expect `�` in that case though

Comment: I am testing the service using Postman and I am getting just ??? instead of ćčđ. š and ž are perfectly ok :-) Totally weird.

Comment: `utf8mb4` means that up to 4 bytes will be stored per UTF8-encoded character instead of 3. European characters don't need so many bytes. Another thing that may affect the results if if the writing application *didn't* translate between encodings and just saved the ISO-8859-1 bytes into the fields. You could check the byte length of the strings in that case and see if it looks unusual

Comment: `Totally weird` not at all. It's the exact symptom you'd get when mixing up different 8-bit codepages. Something went wrong at some point and the text was treated as ASCII (ie non Unicode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that the stored procedure retrieving data referenced a column in another table which had swedish_latin_ci collation.

utf8 charset and utf8_general_ci collation is enough.